# Suppose $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Why is it neccesarily true that $-B := \{-x \mid x \in B\} \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\langle\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\rangle$ be the $\sigma-$algebra of Borel sets in $\mathbb R$.

Suppose  $B  \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Why is it necesarily true that $$
-B := \{-x : x \in B\} \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)?$$

I've tried to construct $-B$ from well-known sets in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ with no success. I know $\mathcal B(\mathbb R) = \sigma(\{((a,b) \mid a < b\})$ etc.

Comment: The first line of your post is not formally correct. When you write "let $x$ be $Y$", you're saying that you take for $x$ an arbitrary $Y$. But from the rest of your post, it looks like you actually mean a very specific measurable space: the reals with Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If anything, you could write "Consider the measurable space $({\bf R},\mathcal B({\bf R}))$" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The function $f(-x)=-x$ is continuous, and
$$
-B=f^{-1}[B],
$$
and note that conitnuous functions invert Borel sets to Borel sets.

Comment: Ahh, yes you are right. I should have thought of using continuous functions to show this !

Comment: Could you think of any smart way of constructing $-B$ using set-operations ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "correct" way to do this is to notice that $x\mapsto -x$ is a Borel map and the preimage of $B$ by it is $-B$, as Yiorgos said.

However, you can do it slightly differently, which may be enlightening if you're new to this (which I'm guessing you are):

1. Notice that for any open set $U$, the set $-U$ is open as well.
2. Then observe that $X\mapsto -X$ preserves countable unions and complements.
3. Finally, you can prove that for Borel $B$, the set $-B$ is Borel either by transfinite induction (with respect to Borel rank), or by noting that the set of all Borel sets satisfying this is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains open sets. Note that the first approach actually allows you to show that the Borel "code" for $-B$ is the same as Borel "code" for $B$, only with all open sets at the first step replaced by inverses.